# UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

In Android I got following **Error in the emulator and some mobile device** but not in **Tablet**:

I can't understand what is the error actually?

I have searched many tutorials but can't find any solution.

Please help me to solve this.

Note: In this application, I have used [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) and theme, may i got because of that library or any other problem?

**My Error Log is:**

```
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:439)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1217)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     ... 45 more
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:916)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:578)
09-11 17:52:57.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9935):     ... 48 more
```

**My XML Layout file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/other_activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/other_activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="@string/name_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsEmailEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsNameEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/email_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsDistributorSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsEmailEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:entries="@array/slide_menu_items"
            android:prompt="@string/select_distributor_prompt_add"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" >
        </Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsAddress1TitleEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsDistributorSpinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/address_1_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsAddress2TitleEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsAddress1TitleEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/address_2_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsAddress3TitleEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsAddress2TitleEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/address_3_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsCompanyAreaSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsAddress3TitleEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:entries="@array/slide_menu_items"
            android:prompt="@string/select_company_area_prompt_add"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" 
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            >
        </Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsPincodeEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsCompanyAreaSpinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/pincode_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsPhone1EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsPincodeEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/phone_1_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsPhone2EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsPhone1EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/phone_2_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsMobileNo1EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsPhone2EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_no_1_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsMobileNo2EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsMobileNo1EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_no_2_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsContactPerson1EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsMobileNo2EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/contact_person_1_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsContactPerson2EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsContactPerson1EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/contact_person_2_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsTinNoEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsContactPerson2EditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/tin_no_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsCstNoEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsTinNoEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/cst_no_cust_all_add"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsVTVRRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsCstNoEditText"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsVTVRLableTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/vt_vr_cust_all_add"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsVTRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/vt_cust_all_add" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsVRRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/vr_cust_all_add" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/custDetailsCFormRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custDetailsVTVRRadioGroup"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsCFormLableTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/c_form_cust_add_all"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsCFormYesRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/yes_cust_add_all" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/custDetailsCFormNoRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/no_cust_add_all" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

#### `styles.xml` in `values` folder:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <style name="SlideBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/slide_bg</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:choiceMode">singleChoice</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/activity_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/activity_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- For Widget -->

    <style name="MyAndroidTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme.DropDown</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme.White</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemAppTheme</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

#### `styles.xml` in `values-11` folder:

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->

    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <style name="MyAndroidTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

#### `styles.xml` in `values-14` folder:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

And also I have a custom theme file:

In `values` folder named `styles_apptheme.xml` and `styles_myactionbar.xml`,
In `values-v11` folder named `styles_apptheme.xml`,
In `values-v14` folder named `styles_myactionbar.xml`

What should I change?

Comment: what are the target sdk, build sdk, max sdk for your project and also the version number for the devices you tried so far?

Comment: min=8 and target=17, max not specified.

Comment: how about the devices you tried?

Comment: Samsung S Duos and Emulator in which it is not worked, but i tried Samsung Tablet it will worked.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

After 2 days I found the solution. If you look at the layout defined in my question, I have a `Spinner`, which is bound with a custom `TextView`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listTextViewSpinner"
    ...
    android:textSize="@dimen/spinner_list_item_text_size"/>
```

Here, I'm using dimension I'v extracted in a dimension resource: `@dimen/spinner_list_item_text_size`.

This has been defined in `dimens.xml` in the following directories:

- `values-sw600dp`
- `values-sw720dp-land`

But **crucially**, I forgot to define it in the default values folder:

- `values`

After defining the resource value (`@dimen/spinner_list_item_text_size`) in `values/dimens.xml`, it worked successfully.

Comment: Your fix helped me - we'd just changed to a much smaller device and exactly the same happened.

Comment: Check each and every `values` folder for your resource.

Comment: Thanks for this grate answer, but I would like to know the reason to define values in each dimens.xml. Because this problem is not occurring in each devices.

Answer (score 67):

In my case the problem was

```
<dimen name="name">12</dimen>
```

instead of:

```
<dimen name="name">12dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Your answer sorted the issue. @Pawel (y)

Answer (score 20):

You find in your logcat before the exception a line like this:

> 08-19 10:05:58.008: W/ResourceType(3999): Failure getting entry for
>   0x7f0a005f (t=9 e=95) in package 0 (error -75)

Search for tis number (here 0x7f0a005f) in the generated Resource.class R.java. The name of the variable is the missing dimen-resource.

Comment: I was having trouble locating the correct file to look in and found using "find in path" to search the project for the number an easy alternative.

Comment: What the use of knowing the problem but can not find where to fix it

Answer (score 11):

For others that get here from a Google search, make sure you're assigning a dimension instead of something else. The logcat will point you to the problem view.

i.e. Somehow, 1 of my layouts had a couple of TextViews with
`android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`

Renamed them to
`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`
and all is well again.

Answer (score 5):

**Solved:** I had the same error, But it turns out i forgot to define a value in `dimens.xml` yet i had defined it in `dimens.xml(w820dp)`. Make sure all the values are defined. Worked for me

Comment: Same problem, only caused an error once I upgraded the appcompat dependencies to 25.3.1

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I forgot to add "dp" to the dimens

```
<dimen name="hpr_trash_icon_frame_width">40</dimen>
<dimen name="hpr_trash_icon_frame_height">36</dimen>
```

To

```
<dimen name="hpr_trash_icon_frame_width">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hpr_trash_icon_frame_height">36dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look to this thread, the problem seems to be exactly the one you're having:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/446

It seems the trick is to do the following:

> I met the same problem today, i couldn't find the reason but finally got a solution.
>   It seems that you cannot put any properties that M9 cannot recognize int theme.xml, just like android:actionBarStyle.
>   So the solution is to make a new theme.xml in value-v14, and put all these properties in it.

Good luck!

Comment: so can i copy `styles_myactionbar.xml` with `theme.xml` in `value-v14`.

Comment: I did not read the whole thread, maybe just try to copy theme.xml first in it to see what happens.

Comment: But i have created custom theme for actionbar, so what can i do.?

Comment: Later they explain this: `Anything in the theme related to the action bar and any action bar or action mode style should be in values-v14/ with the android prefix. Everything non-Android prefixed should be in values/ (along with the regular old theme stuff).`

Comment: I have 15 layout xml file but i got error in only one which i have defined above., which problem exactly, i didn't get.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was the value in the dimension.

`<dimen name="general_container_width">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>`

android was not able to resolve the `@dimen/match_parent` when I was trying to get the value in my custom view.

Comment: me too, i had set 12 instead of 12dp

Answer (score 3):

Verify if dimension reference have "sp" in definition.

< dimen name="my_text_size">12sp< /dimen>

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Using **Android Studio 3.5.3**, I tried to create a new dimen.xml resource from the Android UI creation tool as below:

[image]

It created a resource without adding **"dp"** to the value I provided. Take care of this will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just add in root    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >
```

Answer (score 0):

And for me it was a bad styles.xml that defined a textSize incorrectly:-

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small</item>
    </style>

    ...
</resources>
```

The hint came from the following stack trace and realizing that the above was one of the size related changes I made since last successful run.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:972)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:756)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:615)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:636)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:333)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                      at com.edsglobal.ecbc.AMAinActivity.onCreate(AMAinActivity.java:94)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue.

Analysed it from all the perspectives: qualifiers, dimensions not available in all qualifiers, custom framework changes that were probably done in OEMs. Also tried to understand if that resource is somehow not included in the final app created from our bundle app. Built local bundle and created app for my device from instructions at [Generate a device-specific set of APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#device_specific_apks) but could not reproduce. Nothing suspicious when I looked into resource.asrc with apk analyzer in studio.

With no further clue, finally, we thought if this dimensions is really required. Not really as it won’t affect user experience.

So, solution was to **remove that dimension** from TextView. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had 2 colors file. one was pointing to color-v29.xml and the other was in color.xml. when I removed the file from color-v29 the crash was fixed.