# UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2

Tags: android-layout

Hi everyone I am new to android ,

I get the following crash in the xml. as UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2 in Galaxy tab 10.1.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMCommentsView.<init>(HUMCommentsView.java:77)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMDialog.initUi(HUMDialog.java:73)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMDialog.<init>(HUMDialog.java:53)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMSocialView.initUi(HUMSocialView.java:124)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMSocialView.<init>(HUMSocialView.java:94)
at com.test.colors.fragments.HUMVideoDetailFragment.initUi(HUMVideoDetailFragment.java:235)
at   com.test.colors.fragments.HUMVideoDetailFragment.onCreateView(HUMVideoDetailFragment.java:151)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:538)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:480)
at com.test.colors.views.HUMTextView.<init>(HUMTextView.java:42)
... 30 more
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:hummer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.test.colors"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/dm_cmnt_margin" >

<com.test.colors.views.HUMTextView
    android:id="@+id/cmmnt_txt_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/clr_cmmnts"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sz_cmnt_header"
    hummer:font_type="@integer/fnt_cmnt_head" />

<com.test.colors.views.HUMEditText
    android:id="@+id/cmmnt_edt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/textholder_comments"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/cmnt_add"
    android:padding="@dimen/dm_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/clr_cmmnts"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
     android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/clr_cmmnts"
    hummer:font_type="@integer/fnt_cmnt_edittext" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cmmnt_divder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cmmnt_edt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dm_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dm_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cmmnt_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cmmnt_divder"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dm_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dm_cmnt_lv_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dm_cmnt_lv_margin"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider" >
</ListView>

<com.test.colors.views.HUMTextView
    android:id="@+id/cmmnt_txt_empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cmmnt_divder"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dm_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/cmnt_loading"
    android:textColor="@color/clr_desc"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sz_det_desc"
    android:visibility="gone"
    hummer:font_type="@integer/fnt_empty_txt" />
```

This is my color code used in colors.xml

```
<color name="clr_cmmnts">#999999</color>
```

.Please help anyone...

It crashes in onCreate

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        HUMUtils.Log("onCreateView");
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_video_detail, null);
        mContext = getActivity();       
        return mRootView;
    }
```

in line

```
mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_video_detail, null);
```

Crashes are found only in following devices

```
Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus (GT-P6200) , Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7500), Galaxy Tab 8.9 (GT-P7300)
```

Works fine in other devices

Comment: Post your java code also. In your file `HUMVideoDetailFragment.onCreateView(HUMVideoDetailFragment.java:151)` in this line its throwing error.

Comment: Having the same issue only a Galaxy Tab 3 (maybe other too but only have this one). But works on other brands and models we tested.

Comment: you are using dimen files for dimensions, are you using specific values folders? as in values-mdpi, values-sw360dp

Comment: I recall having this problem when using AppCompat text appearances in platform styled AlertDialogs (or vice versa?). It may or may not have been specific only to some version of support library. Type `0x2` is an attribute reference such as `?android:textColorPrimary` and one of OP's classes is trying to resolve an attribute undefined in the used theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741485/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension)