# InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml

When i try to run my application it crashes and i get the following in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.application/com.example.application.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

.....

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

.....

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

.....

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
```

the error also includes to a line in my own code where i set the content view

this is the xml file i reference to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/summonerName"
                    android:layout_width="439dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:textSize="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/region"
                    android:layout_width="83dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summonerName"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#777"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#f3f3f4"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#dadadc"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

I have no clue what to do with these errors. Can anyone help me onto the right track?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the content of the xml file and the file that is being referenced (if any) in the xml file?

Comment: just check if you have added the values in the xml for these folders `values-sw600dp`, `values-sw720dp-land`, `values`.
check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18844713/3326331) which states the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

All your @dimens should be defined

for example

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You might have added those in for example these folders

- values-sw600dp
- values-sw600dp-land
- values-v19
- values-xxhdpi

Or any other folder of course where they could belong
But don't forget that those also have to be in

- values

They have to be also defined there

if that isn't the problem try to create a value-XXXX folder for every layout-XXXX folder you have

- layout-xhdpi
- values-xhdpi

And

- layout-large
- values-large

for example

Comment: All the dimen values that i use in the xml i posted are declared

Comment: @MeneerVenus Are you 100% ther're declared eveywhere where they should?

Comment: Yes, the values are in the dimens.xml file inside the values folder.

Comment: @MeneerVenus Can you try to put your theme.xml in values-v14 to see what that does?

Comment: I dont have a theme.xml file

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel That was the issue I've just faced in a big project. The dimension value was put in `values-sw320dp` and `values-sw600dp` but not in the default `values`. The funny thing that it crashed occasionally only on some phones. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For me it was 'visibilty' value, defined in 'xlarge', but not in 'large' folder. Very misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

problem was that I used a DrawerLayout and that my minSDK was set to below 14. changing that fixed the problem. The android support and appcompat packages for some reason allow you to use the DrawerLayout, but the DrawerLayout definitions for layouts are missing.

changing the minSDK to 14 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be cause of using high resolution drawable resources.check out drawable file resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the layout was using android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in parent Linear Layout.
The App theme was defined as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
```

I removed it and everything worked fine.