# Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1 when inflating the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.trill.trillapp.customviews.TrillSocialNetworkBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/social_network"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_social_network_bar_height"
    android:background="@color/color01">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/social_facebook_bt"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/button_like_off" />

    <com.trill.trillapp.customviews.TrillNotificationTextView
        android:id="@+id/social_facebook_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/social_facebook_bt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/detail_social_text_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/detail_social_bar_icon_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="@color/color01"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_f14" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/social_twitter_bt"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/social_facebook_bt"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_sns_tw" />

    <com.trill.trillapp.customviews.TrillNotificationTextView
        android:id="@+id/social_twitter_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/social_twitter_bt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/detail_social_text_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/detail_social_bar_icon_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/color01"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_f14" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/social_line_bt"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/social_share"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_sns_line" />

    <com.trill.trillapp.customviews.TrillNotificationTextView
        android:id="@+id/social_line_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/social_line_bt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/detail_social_text_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/detail_social_bar_icon_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/color01"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_f14" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/social_share"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_share_off" />

</com.trill.trillapp.customviews.TrillSocialNetworkBar>
```

I got following error when inflating this layout:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trill.trillapp/com.trill.trillapp.activities.TrillDetailArticle}: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you already include all the value in the dimen in the value folder?

Comment: Per nayoso's comment, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18844713/2821954).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found that i lack of value in dimens.xml file. So it cause error

Answer (score 6):

As with all android resources, dimensions are stored in various qualified values.

```
values\dimens.xml
values-v21\dimens.xml
values-land\dimens.xml
```

It may be that the dimension is available in some, but not all necessary locations.

The easiest fix for this problem, is to add an entry into `values\dimens.xml` which is the fall-back place if any of the specifics fail.

Comment: Yes this is true, I also faced a same situation, and the solution was declaring the missing dimension value in the values/dimens.xml file.