# Strange android xml error : "Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1"

Tags: android-layout, inflate-exception, targetinvocationexception, unsupportedoperation

Here's my xml layout (One by one, I commented out each view and finally keeping a bare minimum textview. Yet, the error comes in). I understand that the error caused due to 3 exceptions

1. Invocation Target Exception
2. Inflate Exception
3. UnsupportedOperationException.

But no clue how to go forward.

EDIT :

So I figured out that the root cause for other exceptions is UnsupportedOperationException.
The detailMessage for this is :
"Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1"

Not sure what to do now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    >

 <!--    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" 
        > !-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/challengeName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Sample Data"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
             />

      <!--  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/challengeDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top"
            android:text = "sdjflsdkjf lsdkfjlskd lskdfjls lskdjfs lskdfjsl sdklfj "
             /> 


       <com.mykontiki.android.helper.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible"
             />  

     </LinearLayout> 


     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/challengeStatusName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Do you wish to accept challenge ? "
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             /> 
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/feed_item_bg"

            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonDecline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_content_decline"

                 />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_done"
                 />
           </LinearLayout>   

    </LinearLayout>   -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Here's the logcat error I'm getting.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mykontiki.android/com.mykontiki.android.ChallengeDescription}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.mykontiki.android.ChallengeDescription.onCreate(ChallengeDescription.java:24)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     ... 10 more
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     ... 23 more
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:999)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:629)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:625)
02-02 22:18:05.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: Thanks @DerGolem. The issue was with the textSize attribute I was using.

Comment: Look at this solution : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18844713/4255269](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18844713/4255269) I hope it will be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741485/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the culprit

```
android:textSize="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

Changed it numerical value. I'm guessing this has got something to do with the App Theme and target device I'm using to test.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`