# Got Fatal Exception Unable to understand the reason

Tags: java, android, xml, fatal-error

I have been working with a project where i made the change in Layout file successfully and run the project. It get Build without showing any errors.

Here is the LogCat Trace:

```
02-09 15:50:42.923    2720-2720/com.blues.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-09 15:50:42.924    2720-2720/com.blues.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blues.app, PID: 2720
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blues.app/com.blues.app.Login_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.blues.app.Login_Activity.onCreate(Login_Activity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.blues.app.Login_Activity.onCreate(Login_Activity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.blues.app.Login_Activity.onCreate(Login_Activity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:666)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1055)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:667)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
            at com.blues.app.Login_Activity.onCreate(Login_Activity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-09 15:50:50.215    2720-2720/com.blues.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2720 SIG: 9
```

**Activity Class**

```
package com.blues.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

/**
 * Created by iSandeep on 2/9/2016.
 */
public class Login_Activity extends Activity {

    EditText Username,Password;
    ProgressBar login_Progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

**Xml Layout activity_login**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.blues.app.Login_Activity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="SkyEdu"
            android:textSize="34dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMyLinearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Username"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="Your Username"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLblPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="Your Password"/>

            <!-- Login progress -->
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/login_progress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2196f3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="SIGN IN"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="NextSky Technologies Pvt. Ltd."/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <!--<ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pageMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pageMargin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pageMargin"
            android:padding="@dimen/pageMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/Chk"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:background="@drawable/main_img"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/minerMargin"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/whiteBg"
                    android:text="@string/LoginHeader"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/whiteBg"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/LoginHeader1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult"
                    android:hint="@string/Username"
                    android:padding="@dimen/LoginTextBoxPadding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/minerMargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/minerMargin" />

                <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult"
                    android:padding="@dimen/LoginTextBoxPadding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/minerMargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/minerMargin"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                    android:text="@string/btnLogin"
                    android:textColor="@color/BtnTextColor"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0"
                    android:shadowRadius="5"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/minerMargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/minerMargin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/minerMargin"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Till now, I have tried for clean and build, Creating new Activity for the same task.  but its giving the same exception.

if you need any other information do mention in comments. Thank you.

Comment: Its a problem with your activity xml layout. Can we see it?

Comment: post your xml file for this actiivity. There is some issue in xml

Comment: Share your xml and class file

Comment: `Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1` says that you had assigned wrong parameter to dimension. Provide your xml code of `Login_Activity`

Comment: your code has 4 different exceptions in logCat trace. Can you please add code.

Comment: I just have edited the question with the Layout file and Activity class file

Comment: Visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741485/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

is not a valid textSize. Either replace with a valid text size i.e. 14sp or use:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Replace

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

with

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

For more detail visit
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741485/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension) link

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AndroidDev and @jvrodrigues for your answers I have combined your answers and now its working fine.